# Symfony2 - Saving child and parent from the same form

Tags: symfony, entity, parent-child

I'm new to Symfony2 and i've been struggling with an issue handling a form submission. I can't help feeling i'm missing something stupid, but after googling and not findind any solutions I thought i'd post my problem here.

So, I have a form to create a child entity and edit a couple fields on a parent entity. To build the form i've used the FormBuilder, where i added two form types (one for the child and one for the parent). The parent type includes the ID field for the parent.

On the action that handles the form submission i'm calling handleRequest which fails because:

> Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "setId()", "_*set()" or "*_call()" exist and have public access in class "Ahms\MyBundle\Entity\Parent".

This happens when the parent id field is part of the form, when it's not part of the form this runs smoothly.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you create the Form from child Controller, you have to declare id in child class and have to writ `public function setId($id)` and `public function getId()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could create setId method, in the parent entity. But that seems wrong, as i'm not supposed to be changing entity ids. And, if that helps to better understand my problem, i'm creating the form using the child entity.

Comment: if you created the the form child controller and id is not in child entity, u have to add that. you can add it as another name. can you please upload your child entity and controller..than I can change it